# Bidimensional splines, strictly increasing in one argument

Tags: r, spline

I am working in R. I want to specify flexibly a function q(X,Y) where q is strictly increasing with respect to X (but not necessarily with respect to Y).
I want to use bidimensional splines but I don't know how to do (how to impose the monotonicity constraint in 2D).
So far, my method is to select several values of Y, and for each values of Y, I compute a monotone splines with respect to X. And then I interpolate to create the whole function q. But I wonder if it was possible to do all this in 1 step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scam` package has the following capability:

> `smooth.construct.tesmi1.smooth.spec`:
> Tensor product smoothing constructor for a
> bivariate function monotone increasing in the
> first covariate

Thus

```r
scam(z ~ s(x, y, bs = "tesmi1"), data = ...)
```

should fit a penalized regression spline that is monotonically increasing in `x` and unconstrained with respect to `y`.

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Thanks!